# How can I download images from app in android emulator, even they don't have download options?

Tags: android, emulation

i want to save images to local from an app that has no button for downloading, is it possible to still save images using android emulator? i tried to google a solution but couldn't find any, didn't find anything on github either, left me wondering if it's actually possible to do.

Comment: You can take a screenshot and clip the resulting image.  There's no way to actually download it, because nothing but the app itself knows where the image comes from (which may not even be downloaded).

Comment: You want to download images from where? Of course its possible without a button. Why do you think its not?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.